# Firefox/Thunderbird export public key

Tags: encryption, certificate, digital-signature

I have imported a .p12 file inside Firefox/Thunderbird, now I would like to export its public key (without using openssl or whatever command line code), so I can distribute it and people can encrypt/verify my signature.

Is it possible to do this only using builtin tools ? ie : from the certificate manager found in Firefox/TB (Options > Advanced/Certificates) ?

I'm a bit confused with all these different formats :

What I see from the aforementionned window in the "your certificates" tab, is that I can 'save' my certificate (which outputs a .p12). So both public & private key right ?

Now if I click on "show" for a given certificate, and I go to the details Tab, there is an export button that opens a save dialog with several possible formats (crt, pem, pem-chained, der, pkcs#7, ...). Will this also export the private key ? Or is it safe to export (no private key) to any of these format and distribute the output file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article is quite helpful](https://myonlineusb.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/what-are-the-differences-between-pem-der-p7bpkcs7-pfxpkcs12-certificates/)

PKCS#7 is definitely what I want in my case (public certificate dissemination for signature/encryption).

So from the certificate view tab of Firefox : click on "show" for a given certificate, then switch to the other tab and export in pkcs#7 format

However the fastest way to share the public key is probably to send a signed email

Comment: I feel this answer stub. I extended my case here about Thunderbird/Icedove export http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/349348/16920